# I want to select value from react select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [brand_id, setBrandId] = useState([])

const handleBrand = (e) => {
  setBrandId(e.target.value);
  console.log('hii')
}
```

below is react select in a component

```
<SearchableSelect
  label={'Brand'}
  important
  placeholder="Select Brand"
  value={brands}
  options={brand}
  handleChange={(e) => handleBrand(e)}
/>
```

The error is

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Comment: can you please mention which npm package you are using for SearchableSelect ?
or please mention code if it is custom

Comment: The library may provide value of the selected item, not the event object. Try `console.log(e)` at first and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the react select library return the value object in onChange so, Your handler function should be look like:

```js
const handleBrand=(brand)=>{

    setBrandId(brand.id);
    console.log({brand});
}
```

and in jsx

`handleChange={handleBrand}`

Check out the react-select props docs to learn more about Select props

https://react-select.com/props#select-props

*search onChange method to explore.*